# Is it possible to find a function $f$ such that $f(ue^{x^2})$ is uniformly Lipschitz in $u$ and $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

The title of this question is quite self-explanatory, I was wondering if it's possible to find a function $g(x,u)=f(ue^{x^2})$ is a (uniformly) Lipschitz continuous function both in $u\in\mathbb R$ and $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.